# Sorting multiple field values from Input XML to top in the Output XML

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

**Sorting the same field values from xml to top and rest field values to bottom.**

**this is my input to xslt:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<feed>
    <entry>
        <name>David</name>
        <updated>AA123</updated>
        <title>BB123</title>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <name>John</name>
        <updated>AA123</updated>
        <title>AA123</title>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <name>Jenny</name>
        <updated>CC789</updated>
        <title>TT789</title>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <name>Dan</name>
        <updated>CC456</updated>
        <title>HH456</title>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <name>Steve</name>
        <updated>CC456</updated>
        <title>CC456</title>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <name>Jenny</name>
        <updated>AB456</updated>
        <title>DD789</title>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
        <feed>
        <entry>
            <name>John</name>
            <updated>AA123</updated>
            <title>AA123</title>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <name>Steve</name>
            <updated>CC456</updated>
            <title>CC456</title>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <name>David</name>
            <updated>AA123</updated>
            <title>BB123</title>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <name>Dan</name>
            <updated>CC456</updated>
            <title>HH456</title>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <name>Jenny</name>
            <updated>AB456</updated>
            <title>DD789</title>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <name>Jenny</name>
            <updated>CC789</updated>
            <title>TT789</title>
        </entry>
    </feed>
```

**Below XSLT is not SORTING in correct way:**

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/feed">
  <Customer>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="entry" group-by="updated">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="title">
      <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:sort select="updated"/>
                <xsl:sort select="title"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </Customer>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**I have a requirement to SORT same FIELD values of field name "updated" and "title". If both the field values are same then it should come first in the OUTPUT XML and then later the different field value.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to do:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/feed">
    <feed>
        <xsl:perform-sort select="entry">
            <xsl:sort select="number(updated = title)" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        </xsl:perform-sort> 
    </feed>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Michael,
If the value of Fields "updated" and "title" are same then they should come in top of Output xml and if the values are different then they should come in bottom after all the same field values are captured.

Comment: Well, that's much simpler. See if the edited version works for you.